# React navigation. Render extra views on top of navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigator

I'm trying to create a React Native app that renders an area with interchangeable screens and fixed view with some additional data/menu.  I tried [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) solution form official React Navigation, but I can't make it work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Text, View,} from 'react-native';

import Details from './DetailsScreen';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
   Main: {screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
   header: null
   }
  },
   Details: {
    screen: Details,
  },);

class App extends Component {
  static router = {
    ...RootStack.router,
    getStateForAction: (action, lastState) => {
      return MyStack.router.getStateForAction(action, lastState);
    }
 };

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Foo</Text>  //this is rendering
        <RootStack navigation={navigation}/>  //this is not
     </View>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Article form link suggests that I can wrap object created with `createStackNavigator()` in a parent View, but it renders only when it is the only thing returned from `render()`, otherwise it seems to be ignored. Example from link claims that it is possible to "render additional things", but I can't make it work. Is it possible to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//wrapper.js

function wrapNavigator(Navigator, Wrapper, wrapperProps = {}) {
  const WrappedComponent = props => (
    <Wrapper { ...props, ...wrapperProps}>
      <Navigator {...props} />
    </Wrapper>
  );

  WrappedComponent.router = Navigator.router;
  WrappedComponent.navigationOptions = Navigator.navigationOptions;

  return WrappedComponent;
};

//app.js

const App = (props) => <View>
  <Text>Some text...</Text>
  {children}
</View>

export default wrapNavigator(Stack, App);
```

But this will not work if there are no parent navigator for App component.